# AR floor recognize and interactions

Tags: unity-game-engine, arkit, vuforia, arcore, angular-foundation

I'm as the new of AR development. I want to create AR demo app, but I face some problems.
could anyone help me to solve below problems:
. Does it possible to recognize the floor, if I want to placement with big 3D object ( around 3 meter x 1.5 meter )?
. How can I touch screen to placement only one object on the floor? after that, can disable or enable (buttons) plane detection and still appear 3D object, that we have added to interact on 3D object.
. After added one 3D object, How can we make interaction on 3D object? ex: rotation or scale.

could you share me the tutorials or other links to solving that problems?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

you're in luck. there is a video that shares how to make almost everything exactly like you want it. Also if you want to read over the components that enable you this I'll give you the link to the Vuforia official website documentation when they go over each component and how it works.

Video link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0O6VxnNRFyg

Vuforia link: https://library.vuforia.com/content/vuforia-library/en/features/overview.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer and sharing.
How can I interacts on 3D objects? example: I touch on screen to move, rotate, scale.